# Convert Access IIF To SQL Server Case

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am attempting to convert an access 2013 `IIF()` statement to a SQL Server 2008 `case` statement, but I am getting an error of

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I am sure this stems from my incorrect conversion, but what must I do to properly convert this syntax?

**Access**

```
((val1*mk)+val1)+IIf(ffsaa="0",0,6) AS CC
```

**SQL Attempt**

```
((val1*mk)+val1)+case when ffsaa=0 then 0 else 6 end) AS CC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a opening bracket at start of the `case`. Use:

```
((val1*mk)+val1)+(case when ffsaa=0 then 0 else 6 end) AS CC
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Case` statement at all. You are trying to **add** a value(`ffsaa`) to another computed value. `0` does not make any difference in addition unless you have a value other than `0`

```
Select ((val1*mk)+val1) + ffsaa
```